# Adjust <nz-date-picker> (Ng-Zorro) width

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using Ng-Zorro for template styling and am currently implementing an date picker, which I would like to have sitting flush with the dropdown menu above it.

I'd like to manually adjust the width of the date-picker within the template, but I'm seeing this [link](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/1614) saying that the width cannot be adjusted...

Trying out html in-line styling did not do anything, so now I'm curious if anyone has been able to readjust the width of the nz-date-picker with Ng-Zorro.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

May be you need to set the  `<nz-date-picker>` `display:block` first

then set the `span class="ant-calendar-picker"`  `width:100%`

hope this could help u.

Comment: Great!  I will certainly test this out!
Thanks.

Comment: if it works , could u check my answer ? thanks a lot !

Comment: Oops, I completely forgot...
Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: how to apply css? already wrote css with same class name .ant-calendar-picker but not displaying in styles in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following should work to your component's styling should work for you. The additional styling mentioned in the other response is not necessary for me.

```
nz-date-picker {
  display: block;
}
```