# How to change width of date picker in nz-zorro

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to change width of [nz-date-picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCjmT.png) in Ant design in Angular using CSS. How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust <nz-date-picker> (Ng-Zorro) width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291234/adjust-nz-date-picker-ng-zorro-width)

Comment: Please could you share your code. e.g. have you applied `width` to your selector and what is the `block` (e.g. display)?

Comment: <div nz-col nzSpan="16">
        <nz-form-control>
                <nz-date-picker
                    [nzMode]="dateMode"
                    nzShowTime
                    formControlName="openingDate"
                    (nzOnOpenChange)="handleDateOpenChange($event)"
                    (nzOnPanelChange)="handleDatePanelChange($event)"
                    id="dp"
                    >
              </nz-date-picker>
        </nz-form-control>
    </div>

Comment: This is my code

Comment: Does @Sri9911's comment help?

Comment: Sorry, what should I do?

Comment: @pushpakumara No need to be sorry. Did you have a look at [Adjust <nz-date-picker> (Ng-Zorro) width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291234/adjust-nz-date-picker-ng-zorro-width) ?   Though I have not tried the solution myself but the context of both the questions is same and the latter one does have an accepted answer. It should be helpful.

Comment: yes, I tried it. it's ok. but I want to use it in media queries. Then I don't know how to apply css for nz-datepicker in a media query.

Comment: I have a problem of width of nz-date picker, when browser size is decreased to mobile size.so I want use styles for a nz-date picker in the media queries.

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions:

1. Add in styles picker class and set width, for example:

   .ant-calendar-picker {
       width: 100%;
     }

   and html `<nz-date-picker [nzStyle]="{'width': '100%'}" ...>`
2. You can set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in you component and in styles call class

   .ant-calendar-picker {
       width: 100%; // to override inline ng zorro span style width;
     }